# div cann't scroll to bottom on mounted vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, vuejs3, scrollbar

I have a chat template where I want scrolling the div that contain messages to the bottom when I open the discussion 
but it doesn't work on mounted the component, it workd just when I send message,
despite I call the function in `mounted` hook 
Any suggestion to resolve it ? 
this is my component :

```
<script>
// import section    
export default {
  components : {
  //...
  },
  props: {
    contact: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
    messages: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      auth : null,
      newMessage : {
        message: "",
        from_id: null,
      },
      container : null
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.auth = usePage().props.value.auth.user
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lastMessages()
    this.getMessages()
  },

  methods: {
    async sendMessage(message) {
      if (message == "") return;

      this.newMessage = {
        ...this.newMessage,
        message: message,
        to_id: this.contact.id,
        from_id : this.auth.id
      };
      //Pushes it to the messages array
      this.messages.push(this.newMessage);
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.lastMessages()
      })
...        
    },
    getMessages() {
     ....
    },
    lastMessages () {
      this.container = this.$refs.messages
      this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div  class="flex-1 p:2 sm:p-6 justify-between flex flex-col">
    <div clas="...."   >
      <HeaderChat :contact="contact" />      
    </div>
    <div ref="messages" class="..."    >
      <ChatMessage :messages="messages" :contact="contact" :auth="auth" />
    </div>    
    <InputBloc @send-message="sendMessage" :contact="contact">
      <slot />
    </InputBloc>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: any messages in the developer console?

Comment: @JaromandaX No it's all ok, even when I logged `this.$refs.messages`  in `mounted` it show the entire div

Comment: you could try wrapping that code in mounted with `this.$nextTick(() => {`

Comment: @JaromandaX not work again :(

Comment: Does your Method `.getMessages()` retrieved the Messages from an API and inserts them? If so, you should first retrieve them, and after the retrieval scroll to bottom. Just swap the call of the Methods in your `mounted()`-Hook.

Comment: @IISkullsII Yes I tried this also but nothing works ...

Comment: Might your `getMessages()` Method be asynchronous, which might interfere with the order of execution.

Comment: `I tried this` doesn't look like you did

Comment: @IISkullsII no it is not asynchronous , it use an `laravel Echo`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution in the mounted :

```
  this.$refs.messages.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

---

a second solution is to add dynamic refs when you make your messages loop inside the component ChatMessage example :

ChatMessageComponent :

```
<div v-for="(val, index) in messages" :key="index">
    <div :ref="'chat' + index" >{{chat}}</div>
</div>
```

OtherComponent :

```
   this.$refs["chat" + this.messages.length].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: why `this.$refs["messages"]` instead of what every normal programmer does ... `this.$refs.messages` ?

Comment: I was giving the quick fix, whatever
`this.$refs.messages`

Where

`this.$refs["messages"]`

It's mainly to help him understand the logic behind it but if you prefer `this.$refs.messages` that's ok too

Comment: well, the code in the question uses it :p

Comment: yes sorry I didn't pay attention as I was thinking of a solution where it will have to concatenate a number with text.

Comment: @Mysterdev I use a for loop on `contactComponent` in the parent componnent and when I clicked on a contact the `chatMessage` will be load their props (messages) and show it

Comment: I modified my first example with this.$refs.message @JaromandaX :p

Comment: the for loop is inside
      `<ChatMessage:messages="messages" :contact="contact":auth="auth" />`


Nope ?

In any case, I advise you to dynamically add a ref to be able to catch the last message and scroll over it.

As I don't have all the code I could be wrong but I thought your loop was in chatMessage

Comment: @Mysterdev Yes I have a for loop inside ` ChatMessage` I tried your solution but it gives me `undifined` when I log `this.$refs["chat" + this.messages.length]` I tried also to log `this.$refs["chat1"]`  for testing but also it is undifined

Comment: if you want to make a codesandbox I could help you
But since I don't have all the code in front of me, it's hard to see the problem.

Comment: @Mysterdev Thank you, I resolved it by adding `watch` on `messages` prop in the component who is I mentionned in question : `messages: function () {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.lastMessages();
      });
    },` and finaly it works. I dont know why the first solution wan't working ...

Comment: Nice !!!!! Good luck for the future